# Excluding tests from execution by PIT

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, mutation-testing, pitest

I have to exclude my integration tests from their execution by PIT. There is an option `excludedTestClasses` since version 1.3.0. I tried to pass over these tests by the following configration of the Maven plugin of PIT.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
    <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <mutationThreshold>80</mutationThreshold>
        <targetClasses>
            <param>de.comp.proj.*</param>
        </targetClasses>
        <excludedTestClasses>
            <param>**/*IT.java</param>
        </excludedTestClasses>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

However PIT is still executing all tests with the suffix `IT`. I had a look the the source but got lost in the night ;-)

So, how can I skip my integration tests?

Comment: What about executing the plugin with the -DskipITs -Dskip.integration.tests=true parameters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PIT filters are matched against the class names in the compiled binary, not against the source file name.

Your filter should look something like

```xml
<excludedTestClasses>
    <param>de.comp.**.*IT</param>
</excludedTestClasses>
```

`de.comp.*IT` excludes all tests in the package `de.comp`. Using `de.comp.**.*IT` all tests in subpackages are also ignored.

Comment: I thought the filter `filenameToClassFilter()` removes `.java`.

Comment: Can I use something like `de.com.**.*IT` to exclude all IT below of a specific subpackage? I failed with `**/*IT`.

Comment: To exclude all tests ending with the suffix `IT` in all packages I can use `**.*IT`.

Answer (score 9):

For those using the Gradle plugin :

```
pitest {
    excludedTestClasses = ['de.comp.**.*IT']
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I use pitest-maven version 1.4.2.

This config works fine for me:

```
<excludedTestClasses>          
  <excludedTestClass>de.com.**.*IT</excludedTestClass>
</excludedTestClasses>
```

Maybe following syntax was for older versions of pitest-maven:

```
<excludedTestClasses>
    <param>de.comp.**.*IT</param>
</excludedTestClasses>
```